# Pull username and password variables into JS call in karate

Tags: karate

I'm trying to do some basic authorization by using the javascript function *(basic-auth.js)* here to encode:

```
function fn(creds) {
var temp = creds.USER_NAME + ':' + creds.PASSWORD;
var Base64 = Java.type('java.util.Base64');
var encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(temp.toString().getBytes());
return 'Basic ' + encoded;
}
```

Here is my authorization feature file:

```
@tests=auth
Feature: Auth Management
Background:
    * url baseUrl
@test=accessToken
Scenario: generate access token
    Given path '/oauth2' + '/token'
    And header Authorization = call read('basic-auth.js') { username: '#(USER_NAME)', password: '#(PASSWORD)' }
    And form field grant_type = 'client_credentials'
    When method POST
    Then status 200
    * def accessToken = response.access_token
```

I'm trying to call in the username and password from a stored .yml (karate-config-stg.yml) using the format of `#(USER_NAME)` isn't pulling in the variable from the config file even through from that same config I'm getting the baseUrl without issue. Any help on this one is very appreciated! this is a new concept I'm trying to learn.

karate-config-stg.yml all fields are deleted for this post, in my local they have the appropriate values for staging:

```
baseUrl: ''
USER_NAME: ''
PASSWORD: ''
```

Comment: At first glance - I would think of the difference between baseUrl & USER_NAME is 'underscore'. As its working for baseUrl, Can you give a try without underscore ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why it wasn't working properly, the issue was in my js function - instead of using the variable name of `creds.USER_NAME` and `creds.PASSWORD` I just needed to change the names to `creds.username` and `creds.password` in line 2. In my header authorization I set the variables for those 2 fields with the information from my .yml file.

Comment: I suggested the same n comment though! :)

Answer (score 0):

To call the username and password variables from the YAML file, you need to specify the file name in the call statement.

Here's an updated version of your code:

```
@tests=auth
Feature: Auth Management
Background:
* url baseUrl
@test=accessToken
Scenario: generate access token
Given path '/oauth2' + '/token'
And header Authorization = call read('basic-auth.js') { username: '#(karate-config-stg.USER_NAME)', password: '#(karate-config-stg.PASSWORD)' }
And form field grant_type = 'client_credentials'
When method POST
Then status 200
* def accessToken = response.access_token
```

In the above code, the YAML file name (karate-config-stg.yml) is specified along with the keys (USER_NAME and PASSWORD) in the call statement.